# Reverse animation on hamburger button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to animate a hamburger button. The problem is that the animation works great only for the first click, and I do not know how to make the second click do the reverse animation. I'm not sure if this can be done without using keyframes. Ps. brackets in css are not formatted because its compiled from scss.

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
var nav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-items")[0];
var line1 = document.getElementsByClassName("line1")[0];
var line2 = document.getElementsByClassName("line2")[0];
var line3 = document.getElementsByClassName("line3")[0];

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav_items.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  line1.classList.toggle("first-line");
  line2.classList.toggle("middle-line-hidden");
  line3.classList.toggle("last-line");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   }

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: blue;
  }

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 25px; }
  #logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; }
  #logo a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1; }

.nav-items {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: black; }
  .nav-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 15px 0; }
    .nav-items a:first-child {
      margin-top: 0; }
    .nav-items a:hover {
      color: yellow; }

#hamburger {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
  }
  #hamburger .line1,
  #hamburger .line2,
  #hamburger .line3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s linear; }
  #hamburger .line1 {
    top: 3px; }
  #hamburger .line2 {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
  #hamburger .line3 {
    bottom: 3px; }

.nav-open {
  visibility: visible; }

.middle-line-hidden {
  animation: hamburger-mid-line 0s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.3s; }

.first-line {
  animation: hamburger-first-line 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; }

.last-line {
  animation: hamburger-last-line 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; }

@keyframes hamburger-mid-line {
  from {
    visibility: visible; }
  to {
    visibility: hidden; } }

@keyframes hamburger-first-line {
  0% { }
  50% {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
  100% {
    top: 42%;
    transform: rotate(45deg); } }

@keyframes hamburger-last-line {
  0% { }
  50% {
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%); }
  100% {
    bottom: 45%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg); } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="navbar">
      <div class="nav-items">
        <a href="#">link1</a>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        <a href="#">link3</a>
      </div>

      <button id="hamburger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </button>
    </header>


    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the second snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53555325/8620333 .. I made it on hover but you can change it on click

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way is to assign in the css the animation to a class, for example .openedhamburger with the opening animation.

Now create other animation assigned to other class, for example .closedhamburger, with the closing animation.

Finally switch the class asigned to the element with javascript and there it is, whenever a different class is assigned, the proper animation will be triggered.

**Edit**: also, albeit in your case use a two step animation, so this is not applicable, know that using this class-approach, if you enable smooth transitions, then sometimes you can even do it without any animation: simply associate the positions and rotations for the elements on the two states and then because smooth transformations are enabled, animation will ocur.